# Getting Error on adding xml code dynamically in the current rendered XML

Tags: bpmn, forum, bpmn.io, bpmn-js, bpmn-engine

Rendered the BPMN flow diagram on react s UI using bpmn modeler
The flow is rendered from xml on the UI.
XML is rendered already and on the rendered xml we want to add xml code dynamically,
I am having piece of xml code already just only want to append (dynamically) the xml as string and then insert the code and re render again.

**Approach-1 (using DOMParser)**

Explanation of the code is below:

`DiagramService.getCurrentDiagramXml()` is called to retrieve the XML representation of the current BPMN diagram. It returns a promise that resolves to the XML string.

The retrieved XML string is then parsed using `DOMParser()` to create an XML document object (`xmlDoc`).
The parent node where the custom subprocess will be appended is identified using `querySelector()` based on its ID (`Process_1`).

The XML representing the custom subprocess (`childSubProcess`) is defined as a string. This subprocess contains various BPMN elements such as tasks, events, and sequence flows.

Another `DOMParser()` is used to create a document fragment (`fragment`) from the XML string representing the custom subprocess.

Append each child node of the document fragment to the parent node. After appending the custom subprocess, the modified XML document (`xmlDoc`) is serialized back to a string using `XMLSerializer()`.

The resulting XML string (`newXml`).

Finally, `DiagramService.renderDiagramCanvas(newXml)` is called to render the modified BPMN diagram.
Note : We have attributes of the task node as in the format
voice:voiceTaskType , voice:voiceFileInfo

Code:

```
const insertCustomSubProcess = async () => {
try {
const diagramXML = await DiagramService.getCurrentDiagramXml();

// Parsing diagramXML
let parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(diagramXML, "text/xml" );

// Find the parent node
let parentNode = xmlDoc.querySelector(process[id= “Process_1” ]);

// xml code names childSubProcess that we need to append
const childSubProcess = <subProcess id= “Activity_0009n6k” name= “Greetings” >`

<incoming>Flow_1s78vky</incoming>
<outgoing>Flow_16nzjzj</outgoing>
<task id= "Activity_08gzhgi" name= "Greetings" voice:taskType= "playVoiceFile" voice:voiceFileInfo= "{" en ":

{" filePath ":" welcome "," ttsText ":" "," gender ":" "," playSpeed ":" "," voiceFileType ":" libraryFile "," fileUrl ":" "," fileSize ":" "}," es ":{" filePath ":" es/welcome "," ttsText ":" "," gender ":" "," playSpeed ":" ",

" voiceFileType ":" libraryFile "," fileUrl ":" "," fileSize ":" "," id ":" "," option ":" "}}" session:stepName= "PlayGreeting" >

<incoming>Flow_1we1xkv</incoming>
<outgoing>Flow_0ordxhx</outgoing>
</task>
<startEvent id= "Event_0fwsfrr" name= "Greetings_Start_1" >
<outgoing>Flow_1we1xkv</outgoing>
</startEvent>
<sequenceFlow id= "Flow_1we1xkv" sourceRef= "Event_0fwsfrr" targetRef= "Activity_08gzhgi" />
<intermediateThrowEvent id= "Event_12tlhn0" name= "Greetings_Intermediate_1" >
<incoming>Flow_0ordxhx</incoming>
</intermediateThrowEvent>

<sequenceFlow id= "Flow_0ordxhx" sourceRef= "Activity_08gzhgi" targetRef= "Event_12tlhn0" />
</subProcess>;`

// Create a document fragment for the new child XML
let fragment = parser.parseFromString(childSubProcess, "text/xml" );

// Append the new child XML to the parent node
while (fragment.firstChild) {
parentNode.appendChild(fragment.firstChild);
}

// Serialize the modified XML back to a string
let serializer = new XMLSerializer();
let newXml = serializer.serializeToString(xmlDoc);
console.log( "newXml" , newXml);
DiagramService.renderDiagramCanvas(newXml);

} catch (error) {
// log the error here
}
}
```

**Result of Approach-1 :**

> This page contains the following errors:
> error on line 4 at column 683: Namespace prefix voice for taskType on task is not defined

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
Flow_1s78vky Flow_16nzjzj
voice:voiceTaskType and voice:voiceFileInfo are the attributes of the node name task

[image]

**Approach-2 (using string manilpulation)**

Code:

```
const insertCustomSubProcess = async () => {
try {
  const diagramXML = await DiagramService.getCurrentDiagramXml();
  // Find the position where we want to insert the sub-process
  const insertIndex = diagramXML.indexOf('</process>');

  // Define the sub-process XML
  const childSubProcess = `<subProcess id="Activity_0009n6K" name="Hello">
        <incoming>Flow_1s78vky</incoming>
        <outgoing>Flow_16nzjzj</outgoing>
        <task id="Activity_08gzhgi" name="Hello" voice:taskType="playVoiceFile" voice:voiceFileInfo="{"en":{"filePath":"welcome","ttsText":"","gender":"","playSpeed":"","voiceFileType":"libraryFile","fileUrl":"","fileSize":""},"es":{"filePath":"es/welcome","ttsText":"","gender":"","playSpeed":"","voiceFileType":"libraryFile","fileUrl":"","fileSize":"","id":"","option":""}}" session:stepName="PlayGreeting">
            <incoming>Flow_1we1xkv</incoming>
            <outgoing>Flow_0ordxhx</outgoing>
        </task>
        <startEvent id="Event_0fwsfrr" name="Hello_Start_1">
            <outgoing>Flow_1we1xkv</outgoing>
        </startEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="Flow_1we1xkv" sourceRef="Event_0fwsfrr" targetRef="Activity_08gzhgi" />
        <intermediateThrowEvent id="Event_12tlhn0" name="Hello_Intermediate_1">
            <incoming>Flow_0ordxhx</incoming>
        </intermediateThrowEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="Flow_0ordxhx" sourceRef="Activity_08gzhgi" targetRef="Event_12tlhn0" />
    </subProcess>`;

  // Insert the sub-process XML into the diagramXML at the defined position
  const newDiagramXML = diagramXML.slice(0, insertIndex) + childSubProcess + diagramXML.slice(insertIndex);
  console.log("newXml", newDiagramXML);
  // Render the modified XML
  await DiagramService.renderDiagramCanvas(newDiagramXML);

} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error occurred:", error);
  // Handle the error gracefully, e.g., show a message to the user
}
```

}

**Result of Approach-2:**

XML gets updated but due to its internal creation of co-ordinates of the flow , it is not rendering .Below is the xml code for co ordinates that bpmn generates own its own.

```
<bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_0009n6k_di" bpmnElement="Activity_0009n6k" isExpanded="false">
    <omgdc:Bounds x="-1482" y="-2765" width="270" height="120" />
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
```